# `std::unordered_map` emplace error without `std::piecewise_construct`

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have the following code:

```
#include <complex>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<string, complex<double>> um;
    um.emplace(piecewise_construct, make_tuple("test1"), make_tuple(1,1));// works
    // um.emplace("test2", {1,1}); // error here  
    complex<double> z{1,1};
    um.emplace("test3", z); // this works
}
```

I do not completely understand why am I getting an error on the commented line. The `unordered_map` is emplacing a `pair<string, complex<double>>`, and `complex<double>` has a initialization list type constructor, why cannot then the pair can be constructed in place? If I replace the init-list `{1,1}` with a previously constructed `complex<double>`, then it works.

Comment: `{1,1}` is not an expression an does not have a type. Hence, the function template `emplace` cannot deduce its type. You could specify the type explicitly: `um.emplace<char const*, complex<double>>("test2, {1,1});` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @dyp You can probably just explicitly construct the complex in the parameters, rather than specifying both types.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, that's pretty much what the last line does. `um.emplace("test3", complex<double>{1,1});` should work.

Comment: Actually I am a bit confused. Isn't `{...}` of type `std::initializer_list`? And if the object inside the pair provides an `initializer_list` ctor, shouldn't then the `complex<double>` be constructible from the init list? So basically the `template<typename... Args> emplace(Args...)` has the second argument of type `initializer_list`, which should be convertible (implicitly) to `complex<double>`

Comment: @vsoftco Yeah... unfortunately, `{..}` has been used for both *uniform initialization* and to create `std::initializer_list`s. This leads to quite some ambiguity and misunderstandings. *Uniform initialization*, aka *list-initialization* is a general form of initialization that *can* lead to the creation of a `std::initializer_list`. However, the `{..}` (called a *braced-init-list*) in an initialization doesn't have a type itself. Constructors with a parameter of the form `std::initializer_list<something>` are called initalizer-list-constructors. Neither `std::pair` nor `std::complex` has one.

Comment: @dyp, ahhh ok, have to brush up on my `C++11` :) So if `complex<T>` would have had a ctor of type `std::initializer_list`, then my example would've worked.

Comment: No, the problem in your code is that `emplace` is something like `template<class... Args> void emplace(Args&&...);` so that it has to deduce a type for each argument. `{1,1}` does not have a type, so this function template cannot produce a (function) parameter for that argument.