# emplace into `std::unordered_map` with `std::pair` value

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, std-pair

I'm trying to emplace values into a `std::unordered` map like so:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> testmap;
testmap.emplace("a", "b", "c"));
```

which doesn't work, due to:

> error C2661: 'std::pair::pair' : no overloaded function takes 3 arguments

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597127/creating-an-stdunordered-map-with-an-stdpair-as-key) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743599/stdunordered-map-emplace-error-without-stdpiecewise-construct), and it seems like I need to incorporate `std::piecewise_construct` into the emplacement to get it to work, but I don't think I quite know where to put it in this case. Trying things like

```
testmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, "a", std::piecewise_construct, "b", "c"); // fails
testmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, "a", "b", "c"); // fails
testmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, "a", std::pair<std::string, std::string>( std::piecewise_construct, "b", "c")); // fails
```

Is there some way I can get these values to `emplace`?

I'm compiling with msvc2013 in case that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `std::piecewise_construct` and `std::forward_as_tuple` for the arguments.

The following does compile:

```
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::string>> testmap;
    testmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,std::forward_as_tuple("a"),std::forward_as_tuple("b","c"));
    return 0;
}
```